# How long to implement language after rules are done in bison?

Tags: bison

I am writing my own language and i pretty much finished the rules in bison. Now what is left is implementing the right side. There are about 650 lines. The language is less complex then C but still fairly complex. I havent tried implementing the rules except for a test app to learn it. I had many segfaults but got the hang of it.

Each rule was a function call so potentially 600 of these lines are function calls so there may be 500+ functions. Where the functions fairly simple when you tried it? is most of the work these rules or all the other code not in the functions called? Is the effort about split in between?

Comment: Compiler or Interpreter?

Answer (score 1):

Writing the rules is the easy stuff.
I suppose that you are implementing an interpreter.
By you said it seems that you have defined more than  600 rules it is a lot.
You probably have to reduce the number of rules before going further.

What is number of flex pattern ?

A common mistake is to add to many lexical keyword. Then the bison become a nightmare.
As an example I've seen in the past an interpret which redefine in lex many functions of the maths.h, such as `sin` and `cos`... 
Then the developper has defined SIN, COS tokens ... and create the proper yacc action.
It's a lot of job and not extensible !

Recently I have wrote an OOL interpreter and it contains around 150 rules.
And approximatively one half of then are related to the legacy of a ill-birth previous version.
Bytecode compiler and interpretor lines count is approximatively 10000 for the core.